# How to add two numbers in ReactJS with using class component and show the answer in alert box

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-native

here i create one react app which is have component named Sum, i was trying to get answer of Num1+Num2 in alert() message but when i run the code it shows a NaN in alert message. then How can i get my correct output in alert().

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class Sum extends Component {
    constructor(props) {

        super(props);
        this.state = { Num1: '', Num2: '' };

    }

    Add = () => {
        var n1 = parseInt(this.state.Num1);
        var n2 = parseInt(this.state.Num2);
        var ans = n1 + n2;
        alert(ans);
    }
    render() {
        return ( <
            div >
            <
            input type = "text"
            onChangeText = { Num1 => this.setState({ Num1 }) }
            /> <
            input type = "text"
            onChangeText = { Num2 => this.setState({ Num2 }) }
            /> <
            button title = "Add"
            onClick = { this.Add }
            />



            <
            /div>
        );

    }

}
export default Sum;
```

Comment: What is the value of `this.state.Num1` and `this.state.Num2` when you get `NaN`?

Comment: when i enter any value in textbox and press add button it says NaN in alert

Answer (score 1):

Change the 2 input fields as follows,

```
<input type = "text" onChange = { (e) => this.setState({ Num1: e.target.value }) } 
 value={this.state.Num1} />

<input type = "text" onChange = { (e) => this.setState({ Num2: e.target.value })} 
 value={this.state.Num2} />
```

Also when using `parseInt` use it with a radix.
Ex: parseInt(this.state.Num1, 10)

Comment: Thank you @theekshanawj it solve my problem